# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth in utilities pane in Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Someone knows where to set adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth in the utilities (right) pane when editing the storyboard?

Thanks,
Ox

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm in the same trouble right now...

Comment: Yep, see Undo's answer below.

Comment: If you solved the issue please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select your label in the storyboard, and set the drop down to Minimum Font Size. Then in the text field, enter the lowest size your label should drop to to try to fit the contents onscreen:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to attributes inspector on your TextField and under **minimum font size** drop down menu there is a checkbox **Adjust to Fit**.

**Update** added picture.

[image: UITextField attributes inspector]

Comment: I can't see it, could you please post a picture?
BTW, I'm on Xcode 5.

Comment: Cool, what about UILabel? looks like it appears only in text view.

Comment: see Undo's answer bellow for UILabel

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can adjust Font Size to fit width

titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth